# AngularJS Routes arbitrary loading or not loading routeProvider in Chrome

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome

I'm having a problem with AngularJS routing in Google Chrome. Google Chrome seems to arbitrary decide if it wants to load the routeProvider function.

I tested the same application in other browsers like Safari where I don't have this error.

Chrome is loading the main Angular App just not always the route provider which seems like a loading issue but they are in the same file.

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', 'RouteResolverProvider', '$controllerProvider', 
        '$compileProvider', '$filterProvider', '$provide', '$locationProvider', 'AuthServiceProvider',
function ($routeProvider, RouteResolverProvider, $controllerProvider, 
          $compileProvider, $filterProvider, $provide, $locationProvider, AuthServiceProvider) {

    console.log('Loaded Route Provider'); //Check if Chrome loaded the provider, this arbitrary works.

    var route = RouteResolverProvider.route;

    $routeProvider
        .when('/', route.resolve('Index', ''))
        .when('/login', route.resolve('Login', 'auth/'))
        .when('/logout', route.resolve('Logout', 'auth/'))
        .when('/hello', route.resolve('Hello', ''))
        .when('/secure-path/:parameter', route.resolve('Secure', '', true))
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);
```

Comment: do you get any error on you console? also try to run your app w/o the route resolver and the authService provider

Comment: I do not get any errors in the console.

Comment: Also running the app without the services etc does not change the behaviour.

Comment: How angular and angular-route are loaded to the client? Can it be that they can be loaded in incorrect order?

Comment: are you sure your angular app is bootstrapping at all? is there an ng-app="app" in your html?

Comment: @IlyaLuzyanin I use grunt to concat the files (in correct order into one JS file) and load that on my page. 

@DayanMorenoLeon There is an `ng-app` on my page and I did some checks to make sure that the app is bootstrapping. All seems to work...